# Add third party script tags (<script>) to react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-manipulation

I'm creating a component to be included in a big React project, this component loads a group of script tags that looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = XXXX;
    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/XXXX/?value=0;guid=ON;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

I can't change the contents of this script in anyway, so now I'm using **dangerously-set-html-content** npm package to add & execute those scripts successfully, but then I get the following console warning:

```
conversion.js:29 Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

Of course I wish I could tell google to remove that from the code... but, sadly they won't do it, so I would like to know how to be able to load this kind of scripts and make them work.

I tried changing `<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" async></script>` as other people suggested but the warning continues.

Answer (score 0):

You can import any script to your react project like this:

```
loadScript = () => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = "https://yourlink.js";
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

and call this function inside `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` method

Comment: Hey! like I said at the beginning, my main issue is that I can't change the way that scripts are written... I have to add <script> tags like they are written in my question, I can't change them to be dynamically loading using appendChild